# Can the only legal heir refuse to inherit from his/her father in India?

Tags: india, inheritance

If there is exactly one legal heir for a Hindu person's assets and liabilities and that heir does not want to inherit anything (possibly because there is too debt or complexity) is it possible for the heir to completely abandon all rights to the assets and liabilities?

What is the manner of doing so? Just keeping quiet? And what happens to the assets and liabilities then assuming no one comes forward to take responsibility?

Answer (score 4):

A person [can decline to accept an inheritance](https://www.99acres.com/articles/declining-property-inheritance-in-india.html) under the law of India. The mechanism for doing so depends upon the stage of the probate process at the time and the nature of the property, and often involves a notarized document, or a letter clearly expressing an intent not to inherit.

In those cases, the person declining to accept an inheritance (an action sometimes called a "disclaimer" or "renunciation" of an inheritance), and all of that person's descendants, are treated as if they predeceased the decedent from whom the inheritance derives, for purposes of further distribution of the inheritance.